# How to exchange code for token Owin OpenID with 3party Criipto

Tags: c#, .net, security, owin, openid

Im trying to create a user login with BankId, NemID using Criipto.
I'm able to complete the first steps in getting redirected to Criipto for login, login using bankId and then get redirected back to my controller with a code and state.

The documantation then say I can exchange this code for a token
[image]

I've tried to achive this by using the following code in my controller

```
       public ActionResult Index(ContentModel model, string code = null, string state = null)
    {

        GetToken(code);
        return View(model);
    }

    private void GetToken(string code)
    {
        string id = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CriiptoId"]));
        string s = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CriiptoSecret"]));

        var client = new RestClient("https://my-test.criipto.id/oauth2/token");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //string param = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CriiptoId"] + ":" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CriiptoSecret"]);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(id +":" + s));
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        request.AddParameter("code", code);
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44382/member");

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var content = response.Content;
        }
    }

    private string Base64Encode(string pParam)
    {
        var bytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pParam);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes2);
    }
```

But I get Badrequest stating that my code verifier must have at least 43 characters. No value specified.

What I would prefer to do instead is to make the owin security middleware exchange my code for a token by setting this up in my startup extension if that is possible? And how can I achive this?

I'm using a 3rd party extension for using Azure Ad login to sign in as a member in Umbraco and there I pass the url to my metod ExternalLoginCallback as seen in ExternalLogin to the challenge method which then returns back to that method instead of redirecting to the controller. I want to do the same for CriiptoCallback but the redirect still goes direct to the controller

I've tried to config the startup using an extension like follows

```
    public static void ConfigurCriiptoAuth(this IAppBuilder app, string loginMethod, string postLoginRedirectUri)
    {
        string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CriiptoDomain"];
        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CriiptoId"];
        string clientsecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CriiptoSecret"];

        var idOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientsecret,
            Authority = tenant,
            ResponseType = "code",
            //PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44382/member",
            Caption = "BankId",
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44382/member",
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() {
                //AuthorizationCodeReceived = ctx =>
                //{
                //    
                //},
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx => {
                ctx.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = loginMethod;
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            } }
        };

        //app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
                    
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(idOptions);

    }
```

and my owin startup

```
app.ConfigurCriiptoAuth("urn:grn:authn:se:bankid:another-device", postLoginRedirectUri: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureAd:redirectUrl"]);
```

My IdentityAccountController

```
      [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (returnUrl.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            returnUrl = Request.RawUrl;
        }

        string callbackMethod = string.Empty;

        if(provider == "OpenIdConnect")
        {
            callbackMethod = "CriiptoCallback";
        }
        else
        {
            callbackMethod = "ExternalLoginCallback";
        }

        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider,
            Url.SurfaceAction<UmbracoIdentityAccountController>(callbackMethod, new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CriiptoCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        return null;
    }

   private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId = null)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        private string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        private string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        private string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }

            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A request and response can both have a body which is the Content.  Your request is missing the body.  A controller can be used in both client and server.  So you have 4 places where you handle message 1) Client send request : Optional Post 2) Server receives request : Optional Get 3) Server sends response : Optional Post 4) Client receives response : Optional Get.  The post and get are the body of the message (Content).  You are missing the content in "1" above.   The server is getting the request with not body.  Then returning the error message in the response.

Comment: sorry for my incompetence, what should the body of my request look like?

Comment: Every Server is different.  You have to check the server documentation.  The error indicates the body has to have a least 43 characters.

Comment: Put break points in code to determine which methods are being called.  Also make sure you are sending in request the correct id.  For Base 64 use Convert.ToBase64String(id +":" + s)